# PHP Echo back multiple selected from form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

create.php

The first thing I do is create and send each of these to it's own column in my table.

```
    $subCategoryDirectory = $_POST["subCategoryDirectory"];
    $subCategoryDirectory_1 = $subCategoryDirectory[0];
    $subCategoryDirectory_2 = $subCategoryDirectory[1];
    $subCategoryDirectory_3 = $subCategoryDirectory[2];
    $subCategoryDirectory_4 = $subCategoryDirectory[3];
    $subCategoryDirectory_5 = $subCategoryDirectory[4];


+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
| subCategoryDirectory | subCategoryDirectory_2 | subCategoryDirectory_3 | subCategoryDirectory_4 | subCategoryDirectory_5 |  |
+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
| selection            | selection2             | selection3             | selection4             | selection5             |  |
+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
|                      |                        |                        |                        |                        |  |
+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
|                      |                        |                        |                        |                        |  |
+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
```

> update.php

When updating I call and assign each to a variable.

```
$selectUpdate = "SELECT * from table where id=$id LIMIT 1";
$selectUpdateDisplay =  $wpdb->get_results($selectUpdate, ARRAY_A);

foreach ($selectUpdateDisplay as $sqlStuf){    
$cat1 = $sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory];
$cat2 = $sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory_2];
$cat3 = $sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory_3];
$cat4 = $sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory_4];
$cat5 = $sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory_5];
}
```

So I have the table above for which I'd like to echo back into the select form as "selected/highlighted" below when updating. Right now when I update I lose the values from the initial upload.

```
<select id="subCategoryDirectory" name="subCategoryDirectory[]" style="width:100%;" multiple>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat1; ?>"><?php echo $cat1; ?></option>
<optgroup label="Advertising & Media">
        <option value="Advertising &amp; Marketing">Advertising &amp; Marketing</option>
        <option value="Advertising, Marketing, Promotions">Advertising, Marketing, Promotions</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Transportation">
        <option value="Delivery Service">Delivery Service</option>
        <option value="Limousine Service ">Limousine Service </option>
        <option value="Taxicab">Taxicab</option>
        <option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Each time I've tried the echo I get a single value as you can imagine. None of which are selected. Should I test to see if each of the variables is empty and do it the long way? Am I overthinking this?

> UPDATE

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(32) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "112"
    ["nameDirectory"]=>
    string(14) "test to delete"
    ["nameDirectoryAbv"]=>
    string(4) ""
    ["descriptionDirectory"]=>
    string(14) ""
    ["summaryDirectory"]=>
    string(14) ""
    ["addressDirectoryStreet"]=>
    string(11) ""
    ["addressDirectorySuiteNumber"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["addressDirectoryNumber"]=>
    string(5) ""
    ["addressDirectoryPrefix"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["addressDirectoryTwo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["zipDirectory"]=>
    string(5) ""
    ["websiteDirectory"]=>
    string(21) ""
    ["facebookDirectory"]=>
    string(21) ""
    ["twitterDirectory"]=>
    string(21) ""
    ["linkedinDirectory"]=>
    string(21) ""
    ["emailDirectory"]=>
    string(13) ""
    ["contactNameDirectory"]=>
    string(4) ""
    ["phoneDirectory"]=>
    string(12) ""
    ["faxDirectory"]=>
    string(12) ""
    ["categoryDirectory"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subCategoryDirectory"]=>
    string(23) "Advertising & Marketing"
    ["subCategoryDirectory_2"]=>
    string(34) "Advertising, Marketing, Promotions"
    ["subCategoryDirectory_3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subCategoryDirectory_4"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subCategoryDirectory_5"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cityDirectory"]=>
    string(11) ""
    ["stateDirectory"]=>
    string(2) ""
    ["hoursDirectory"]=>
    string(13) ""
    ["image_1"]=>
    string(80) ""
    ["image_2"]=>
    string(92) ""
    ["image_3"]=>
    string(85) ""
    ["image_4"]=>
    string(85) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the data back to the page?

Comment: I'm not really passing the values on to a new page. I'm just calling each category column through MYSQL. Then assigning each $cat1, ect so that I can use them. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not sure why you're triple assigning everything, are you using a framework? Need to see more code from `update.php` which I'm assuming the form html is also on?

Comment: @Bankzilla I've just included all that pertains to the update page. Is that what you were looking for? I'm using Wordpress, but no "framework".

Yes the form is on  update.php

`table` within the MYSQL statement is referencing the original table above.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? `$sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory];` should throw an error. It should be `$sqlStuf["subCategoryDirectory"];`

Comment: Sorry. I manually typed it out. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: Can you edit your question showing the output of `$selectUpdateDisplay`

Comment: Sure. I just included it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for your subCategoryDirectories:

```
$cat = array($sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory_1],$sqlStuf[subCategoryDirectory_2], ...);
```

Using the array in a loop (either a `foreach` or `for`) in addition to `is_set` would allow you to show only items of the array that have been set:

**foreach**:

```
<?php foreach ($cat as $item) { if (isset($item)) { echo "<option value=\""; echo "$item\">$item</option>\n"; } } ?>
```

**for**:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 4;) { if (isset($cat[$i])) { echo "<option value=\""; echo "$cat[$i]\">$cat[$i]</option>\n"; } $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: Intersting idea. The only thing is if I don't check for empty then each option will be listed even if nothing was submitted for cat3,cat4 and so forth.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways you could check whether or not a variable has or value or is even set ( `is_set` would be an example).